# TypeError raised while applying 'LabelEncoder's fit_transform' function to columns of object type

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I am trying to encode columns into numeric format using `scikit LabelEncoder` function.

Below is the head and dtypes of my dataframe.

```
cc_apps.head()

    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15
0   b   30.83   0.000   u   g   w   v   1.25    t   t   1   f   g   00202   0   +
1   a   58.67   4.460   u   g   q   h   3.04    t   t   6   f   g   00043   560     +
2   a   24.50   0.500   u   g   q   h   1.50    t   f   0   f   g   00280   824     +
3   b   27.83   1.540   u   g   w   v   3.75    t   t   5   t   g   00100   3   +
4   b   20.17   5.625   u   g   w   v   1.71    t   f   0   f   s   00120   0   +

cc_apps.dtypes
0      object
1      object
2     float64
3      object
4      object
5      object
6      object
7     float64
8      object
9      object
10      int64
11     object
12     object
13     object
14      int64
15     object
dtype: object
```

Below is what I did to convert the 'object' type columns to numeric.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le=LabelEncoder()
for col in cc_apps.columns:
    if cc_apps[col].dtype=='object':
        cc_apps[col]=le.fit_transform(cc_apps[col])

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
TypeError: argument must be a string or number
```

Why is that I am encountering the error? How to overcome that? Appreciate inputs.

Answer (score 0):

After some research on **satckoverflow** itself, I have found out that the object `cc_apps[col]` is a mixed type and has different data types for different columns. Hence for `le.fit_transform()` to work `cc_apps[col]` shall be forced to string type.

It means, the encoding bit of code will be as follows. And this worked for me.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le=LabelEncoder()
for col in cc_apps.columns:
    if cc_apps[col].dtype=='object':
        cc_apps[col]=le.fit_transform(cc_apps[col].astype(str))
```